# How to optimize multiple images from folder at once (decrease file size) manually in webapi?

Tags: .net, image-processing, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Hi all i am working on webapi i need to  optimize the images from folder here i Had      `Uploaded images into one folder` before uploading in to the `destination folder` i need to decrease the `image size in KB` of total images here i am optimizing a `single image in to 3 different sizes'    (large, thumbnail,medium)' but       image sizes are increased` and saved in one folder
now  i need to optimize those images could u plz help me
how could i do that.    actually i am new to webapi. 
any body could have any idea please help me but one thing i need to do `this manually` 
thankyou in advance

this my controllers

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            var uploadFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Sprites/UploadFolder");
            uploadFolder = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff"));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);
            var streamProvider = new PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(uploadFolder);

            return Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                foreach (var uploadedFile in Directory.GetFiles(uploadFolder))
                {
                    var thumbnail = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "thumb-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                    var medium = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "medium-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                    var large = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "large-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                    ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, thumbnail, 80, 80);
                    ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, medium, 48, 48);
                    ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, large, 128, 128);
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
            });
        }
    }
```

abd this my  class files

```
 public class ImageTools
    {
        public static void Resize(string original, string output, int width, int height)
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromFile(original))
            using (var thumbnail = new Bitmap(width, height))
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail))
            {
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

                ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
                encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                thumbnail.Save(output, info[1], encoderParameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

class file

```
 public class PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider : MultipartFileStreamProvider
        {
            public PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(string rootPath)
                : base(rootPath)
            {
            }

            public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
            {
                return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
            }
        }
```

this is my layout page

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "Upload" }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="image" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

i had created one folder now images are saved in folder but file size increases in kb but we need to be reduce plz help me

Comment: Could you edit your post a bit - it is unclear what seems to be the problem - is resizing images producing increase in byte size? If so - provide some example, like what libraries do you use to do the resizing and how do you use them. I don't believe this has anything to do with webAPI.

Comment: i had updated plz look my code plz help me to do this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an argument to your **Resize** method for a QualityLevel and change the different rendering with this parameter.

You're resizing your images with quality set to full, that's not very efficient.

You should try to specify another file format, I don't know which one you're using but **.PNG** for small images and **.JPG** for bigger one should help. (***.GIF*** too if you really need that extra byte)

Some image treatments should be done before using the images but I guess you don't really have a choice here.

Answer (score 2):

As above your question small change required try this one  just call this file in your controllers i hope it wil help u

```
 public class ImageDecrease
        {
            public static void Resize(Stream original, string output, int width, int height)
            {
                using (var image = Image.FromStream(original))
                using (var thumbnail = new Bitmap(width, height))
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail))
                {
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                    graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

                    ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                    EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
                    encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                    thumbnail.Save(output, info[1], encoderParameters);
                }
            }
        }
```